# General method for discovering the answers to "which header should I include" questions in boost official documentation?

Tags: c++, boost

[This](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/function_output.html) is an example of countless documentation pages in the Boost.org official docs that completely fail to answer the Question Number Zero: "which header file should I include in order to be able to use this thing"?

What is the secret art of discovering answers to these questions **from official boost docs**, as opposed to just grepping the sources for definitions?

Comment: It's an open source project, if you think you can improve the documentation then submit a pull request on GitHub

Comment: Good to know I was not only person who takes headache when including the boost. +1

Comment: Well you have the answer in your question, just look in the headers, the example code or the unit tests. If you want to improve that then feel free to contribute to the project to improve the documentation. Open source library authors are definitely guilty of concentrating on writing the library itself and the documentation is an afterthought. Documentation is often better written by people less familiar with a library as what is obvious to the author and wouldn't need documenting is often not obvious to their users.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, you might have a point if this were about some odd question pertaining to some corner case usage, but this is about Question Number Zero. It's different. It's special. It's THE ONE ABSOLUTELY MINIMAL THING that documentation authors MUST understand that users WILL need.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that the boost documentation could be better but your question as it stands is unanswerable, it's not in the documentation and there is no magic that will make it appear there, somebody has to improve the documentation. Raising a bug on each project's issue tracker is your only other option.

Comment: I find boost libraries organized quite well. In order to use xxx from library yyy usually header like boost/yyy/xxx.hpp needs to be included. In case of the linked page, it is part of `iterator` library and the title says "Function Output Iterator" so in order to use it you need to `#include <boost/iterator/function_output_iterator.hpp>`

Comment: @user7860670 It's even documented, and wasn't even hard to find. I only noticed the specific example after writing my [general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236815/85371), so I added a [specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236918/85371) addressing that specific example `function_output_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

> Note, I'd previously written [a fully general response to the question title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236815/85371)

To answer the specific example:

Go by the library home page: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iterator/doc/ (you can find it from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/ in case you have trouble guessing the URL).

It will show you a top-level index, and the [Specialized Adaptors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#id25) section mentions `function_output_iterator`:

[image]

Clicking on that link takes you here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html

A fragment from the top of that page: [image]

Answer (score 1):

> Note: this answers the title: ***General method** for discovering the answers to "which header should I include" questions in boost official documentation?*.
>
> I've added a specific answer for your example case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236918/85371

My strategy is usually to read the examples, sometimes the tests.

However, this may not be necessary:

1. Most libraries will turn out to have very predictable include patterns.
2. Some will even warn you about which headers to include with pragmas
   (Variant for `variant_io.hpp`, Bind for `bind/bind.hpp` to get the new
   placeholder behaviour, some deprecated headers will hint what to use
   instead)
3. Many libraries (the majority?) include a header-reference section with
   hyperlinks for symbols named throughout. Just click on the type/function
   and inspect the page link to see what
   header.
4. Most documentation samples are actually inlined from the example sources included

Sadly, some libraries do **not** have predictable include patterns, or even
documentation coverage of some aspects. One example, in my experience, would be
Boost Geometry. Luckily, the first approach (by examples and test) usually
works. If all else fails you can always come to StackOverflow or the Boost mailing lists.

### 3. Hyperlinked References

As an example:

[Boost Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) has its header reference in
[doc/html/interprocess/indexes_reference.html#boost_interprocess_header_reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess/indexes_reference.html#boost_interprocess_header_reference).
When you browse the documentation for, say: [Managed Heap Memory:
Boost.Interprocess machinery in heap
memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_heap_memory_external_buffer.managed_heap_memory),
you will find the mention of
[*"basic_managed_external_buffer"*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#:%7E:text=The%20use%20is%20exactly%20the%20same%20as%20basic_managed_external_buffer)
hyperlinks to
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/basic_managed_ext_idm26635.html
in the reference, stating which header it comes from, which again hyperlinks to
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/interprocess/indexes_reference.html#header.boost.interprocess.managed_external_buffer_hpp
in the header reference.

[image]

### 4. Inlined Documentation Snippets

For most of the libraries I'm aware of, the documentation samples are actually
referring to fragments directly taken from working/building example programs.
E.g. the documentation snippet at
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/distinct.html#spirit_repository.qi_components.directives.distinct.using_the_distinct_directive_to_match_keywords
is actually directly compiled-in from
[/libs/spirit/repository/example/qi/distinct.cpp, lines
26-35](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/boost-1.78.0/repository/example/qi/distinct.cpp#L26):

```
//[qi_distinct_description_ident
{
    std::string str("description ident");
    std::string::iterator first(str.begin());
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, str.end()
      , distinct(alnum | '_')["description"] >> -lit("--") >> +(alnum | '_')
      , space);
    BOOST_ASSERT(r && first == str.end());
}
//]
```

To find the full, self-contained, code, there's often a link from the
documentation page, but sometimes a quick file search helps. For example, the
previous sample [does
link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/distinct.html#spirit_repository.qi_components.directives.distinct.example)
to the example source file, but otherwise a `grep "description ident"` works.